# Program to determine the lowest quality encoding a music file went through

Tags: music, file-compression, mp3

I sometimes get some .wav files that might have been converted from low-quality MP3 (e.g. 128 kbps). I am looking for a program to determine/estimate the lowest quality encoding a music file went through. If possible:

- free
- supports Windows 7
- can analyze several files at the same time
- supports most common music file formats (.wav, MP3, FLAC, etc)

---

Some examples of frequency analysis using Audacity that show the impact of the lowest quality encoding a music file went through:

FLAC/WAV (lossless):

[image]

MP3 320 kbps from Beatport:

[image]

MP3 128 kbps from YouTube:

[image]

AAC 256 kbps from iTunes ([they used to be 128 kbps](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1711)!):

[image]

Comment: Have you read this http://www.wikihow.com/Check-the-Real-Bitrate-of-Audio-Files ?

Comment: @Cornelius Thanks, great link (I use Audacity to plot the spectrum)! It's pretty painful to do it manually though, I was hoping to have some software that could go through many music files and detect the upscaled ones.

Comment: I also found that [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net) runs from `cmd` and can create [spectrum data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756237/get-a-spectrum-of-frequencies-from-wav-riff-using-linux-command-line) reports from mp3. Now you need something that will batch analyze those reports.

Comment: There are a lot of things spectrum data unfortunately can't tell you, for example whether a file's been tandem encoded.