# Application to search my music library for low quality tracks

Tags: windows, music, audio

I was listening to my music today and randomly checked the quality of one of my tracks, only to discover it was only 256kbps! This won't do, I prefer to listen to 320 when I can find it.

Does anyone know a Windows app I can run to search through my music files and return tracks or albums that are below a certain quality threshold? Doesn't need to be very fancy, but my library is a little over 18,000 files so it would need to be rather efficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use Windows Explorer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that the bit rate is the encoding, not the actual quality of the track. See [program to determine the lowest quality encoding a music file went through](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3585/903).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. What about if all my files are in nested folders by artist?

Comment: The search is recursive.

Comment: Derp, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what [foobar 2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) *doesn't* do.You could drag in all your music into a playlist, enable the "bitrate" column on your playlist, then you can sort by bitrate. Initial playlist building takes a while (but my music collection's at ~100gb). I'd also recommend having a 'codec' column enabled and since I'd suspect mp3/cbr may have lower bitrates at little loss of quality

Mine looks something like this so sorted. I wouldn't do it this way though

[image]

There's a smarter way to do this -

You can *also* use search (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) to select these out (which I wished I knew before I messed up the order of my music) - you can find a more complete guide to the [query syntax](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Query_syntax) here, or by clicking in that <kbd>?</kbd> in search. You can even copy paste these to a new playlist. or further filter (for example %bitrate% LESS 320 AND %artist% HAS nirvana), so you know which tracks to rip again.

[image]

I'd add its a great, flexible music player, with a lot of awesome options. It'll run portably if you didn't want a permanent install, and all sorts of great plugins.